# Cannot access deja-dup backup

Tags: encryption, external-hdd, deja-dup

My laptop is being repaired and I need to access the files on my encrypted HDD (which I regularly back up with Deja-Dup).

Is there a way of accessing these backed-up files through WIndows or mac?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to boot off a LiveDVD or LiveUSB (12.04 or 12.10) and plug the device in.  Next mount the drive in the computer (or another USB device) by opening it in Nautilus.  If you're not sure where the device is mounted open a terminal and issue the command:

```
mount | grep /dev/sd
```

Or have a look in 'disk utility'

Next, start deja dup and select the external device/pathname to restore from, and the drive of your choice to restore to.

Comment: Ok, for convenience is it possible to decrypt it using Deja-Dup (until I get my laptop back) ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant the external drive partition was encrypted.  Just restore the files with deja dup after booting a liveCD or USB.  See my edited answer.

Comment: You actually *need* to restore the backup with deja-dup as it is encrypted. You need the backup password for that which you hopefully remember.

Comment: I do have the password. I would just like to decrypt the HDD for the time being so I can use my files on a public PC. I can use a Live USB to run Ubuntu on a friends computer but I don't think she'll appreciate me restore ALL my personal files onto her laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Deja-dup uses duplicity, which is available on Windows through dupliciti, which can be downloaded [here](http://code.google.com/p/duplicati/). Try it and tell me how it goes.

Comment: Downloaded and tried to use deja-dup 25.1.1 but it won't recognize the encrypted files when I try to Open, View or Extract them, even when I select "compressed and encrypted files" in the drop-down box.

Comment: Do you mean dupliciti or deja-dup? There's no deja-dup for Windows. Try clicking on this link : http://duplicati.googlecode.com/files/Duplicati%201.3.3.zip